# how to count the number of #Div/0 value in excel

Tags: excel

I wish to count the number of " #Div/0" occurrence in excel, where 1/0 results in "#Div/0" value in excel, may I know anyone has experience how to count the number of it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `ERROR.TYPE` function.

For example, the following array-formula, will count the number of `#DIV/0!` errors in the range `D1:D10`.

```
=SUM(IFERROR(IF(ERROR.TYPE(D1:D10)=2,1,0),0))
```

An array formula must be entered by holding down <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> while hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>.  If you do this correctly, Excel will place braces `{...}` around the formula seen in the formula bar.

[image]

Here is an example showing that `#DIV/0`, when entered as text, is not counted.  Note the two changes in `D9:D10`.  One was entered directly and became an error, the other was entered as a text string.  Note also the formulas adjacent to `D9:D10` indicating `text` vs `error`

[image]

Comment: But when I try to count only for the "#DIV/0!" due to 1/0, but not the string "#DIV/0!", it still counts in, which is not what I want

Comment: @sweetyBaby Are you sure what you think is a string is, in fact, a string? How are you entering it? If I enter that value as a string, the formula does not count it. If I type it into a cell that is formatted as text, it does not count. However, if I merely type that into a cell formatted as General, then it transforms to the error, and not to a text string, and will be counted, as expected, since it is not a text string.

Comment: @sweetyBaby I have added a screenshot demonstrating that `#DIV/0!` when entered as a text string is not counted by the formula.

Answer (score 1):

Use `COUNTIF`.  For example, if you wanted a count of `#DIV/0!` in the first 10 cells of column A you could use this:

```
=COUNTIF(A1:A10, "#DIV/0!")
```

Comment: But what if I wish to count only for the "#DIV/0!" due to 1/0, but not the string "#DIV/0!"？

Comment: @sweetyBaby Then you should be checking the denominator of the quotient directly, so see if it be zero.