# How to count the number of error values in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-2016

There are various error values like #Div/0, #Name? etc. 
Is there a formula where I can count the number of error values in the selected cells?

Comment: What was wrong with [your previous question, which has already received an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49476973/how-to-count-the-number-of-div-0-value-in-excel/49477009?noredirect=1#comment85956551_49477009)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to count the number of #Div/0 value in excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49476973/how-to-count-the-number-of-div-0-value-in-excel)

Comment: the answer in your previous question doesn't count the text `"#DIV/0!"` with either `=COUNTIF(A:A,"#DIV/0!")` or `=COUNTIF(A:A, 0/0)`

Comment: @Slai just tested the "=COUNTIF(A:A,"#DIV/0!")" that you say does not work and it counts "#DIV/0!" fine on the worksheet I set up...

Comment: @SolarMike my comment is that it does work, and doesn't count cells that contain the text `#DIV/0!` instead of the error value `#DIV/0!`

Comment: @Slai well that is interesting - just did 3 calculations dividing by zero to produce three div/0 errors and they are counted, which is what you say. Then I copied and pasted them in the next column as values and they still get counted so it seems to recognise the text fine... Not sure what I'm not doing then...

Comment: @SolarMike format a cell as Text, and enter `#DIV/0!` in it

Comment: @Slai Ahh, once formatted as text it does not work - all my cells were formatted as General...

Answer (score 3):

```
=SUMPRODUCT( --ISERROR(A1:C3) )
```

Answer (score 1):

VBA .SpecialCells can return a count of errors returned by formulas.

```
Option Explicit

Sub errorCount()
    On Error GoTo noerror
    With Intersect(Selection, Selection.Parent.UsedRange)
        Debug.Print .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors).Count & " errors in selection"
        Exit Sub
noerror:
        Debug.Print "no errors in selection"
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following with Ctrl + Shift + Enter as is array formula, replace I3:I4 with your range

```
=SUM(IFERROR(I3:I4,1))
```

The {} are not physically entered. They will appear around the formula

when you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>Shift</kbd> +<kbd>Enter</kbd> to enter the formula in the cell i.e. the result in the cell will look like:

```
={SUM(IFERROR(I3:I4,1))}
```

Comment: But if I type "#DIV/0!” for a normal string, it also counts as an error,

Comment: #DIV/0! is an error string so if you type that yes it will be recognised as such. Why would you type that?